# onCreate send email to self in AppMaker?

Tags: google-app-maker

Still learning about app maker and found this presentation at Google I/O '17  "Build Powerful Custom Apps Fast with App Maker on G Suite"

At timestamp 15.24 sec some code is shown on the screen showing how to send an email to yourself once someone creates a new item can.

https://youtu.be/Q84HQgI3Dd8?t=15m27s

**Question**

Can anyone advise where and how this code can be implemented its pretty cool and would be a great feature to add when a record is created

Thanks in advance and no worries if you cant help

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for model events:

https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/events

In App Maker models typically have onCreate, onSave, onLoad, onDelete events. It is the best place to handle email notifications. Here is a link to App Script email API:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to go to the [Codelab for App Maker](https://sites.google.com/a/google.com/app-maker-code-labs-v3/lab-3). The section **Building a form to send an email** describes the whole process.

The steps to highlight are:

**Step 11** - Set the onClick property of the button as a custom action with the code:

```
var widgets = widget.parent.descendants;
var to = widgets.To.value;
var subject = widgets.Subject.value;
var msg = widgets.Msg.value;
widgets.EmailStatus.text = 'Sending email...';

SendEmail(to, subject, msg)
```

**Step 13** - Add the following ClientScript code:

```
function  clearEmailForm(){
  var formWidgets = app.pages.Basic.descendants;
  formWidgets.EmailStatus.text = "";
  formWidgets.Msg.value = "";
  formWidgets.To.value = "";
  formWidgets.Subject.value = "";
}

function SendEmail(To, Subject, Msg){
  var status = app.pages.Basic.descendants.EmailStatus;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(result) {
   status.text = 'Email sent...';
   clearEmailForm();
    })
    .SendEmail(To, Subject, Msg);  
}
```

**Step 14** - Now add the corresponding code to the ServerScript.

```
function SendEmail(to, subject, msg){
  MailApp.sendEmail(to, subject , msg);
}
```

Comment: Cheers Morfinismo thats fantastic the link to the the Codelab for app maker didnt work (insufficient privileges)  but the script extracts above should be enough for me cheers for the feedback much appreciated :-)

Comment: Hi Morfinismo just checking out the above code on a fresh app and unfortunately it is and it isnt want im looking for. I have already followed along the process of creating Client and Server Scripts to send a basic email here: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/tutorials/call-scripts/ What I would like to do is link this process to a form so in the video above when the user clicks the Submit button after filling out a form their entry is recorded into the DataSoure table and a copy of their info is sent to Staff / manager cheers of the feedback all the same :-)